# How to call an importe function javascript and vuejs?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, console

I'm expecting to call the function that is previously imported. But I see no result.

```js
<script>
import { search } from '../modules/api/drafts'
...
methods: {
    draftSearched (payload, search = this.search) {
      console.log('search', search)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably naming problem

The param of draftSearched (search) and the import (search) is the same, try to change it to different names

Answer (score 0):

The function `search` should be used inside of your method, but not as a parameter.

If `search` is a function that should be inside of `draftSearched` here is how to do it:

```js
<script>
import { search } from '../modules/api/drafts'

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    async draftSearched(payload) {
      const result = await search(payload);
      console.log('search result', result);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```